# react-select value one step behind

Tags: reactjs, select, onchange, react-select

I'm using react-select and passing the value to a backend node script - but the value passed is always the previous value of the select box -

so in this example when it loads and I change the dropdown to Lancaster the alert is blank. If I then select London, the alert says Lancaster, then no matter what I select the alert will say London etc.

any ideas?

```
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import Select from 'react-select';

export default class PersonList extends React.Component {


  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      cines: [],
    };
  }
  handleSubmit(c){  
      axios.get(`/api/groups/`, {
      params: {
        City: c
      }
    })
      .then(res => {
        const cines = res.data;
        this.setState({ cines });
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      })
    
  }
  handleChange = (event) => {   
    event.persist();
    this.setState({ value: event.target.value});
    alert(this.state.value);
    this.handleSubmit(this.state.value); 
  }
 

  render() {
    const { options, value } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <select id="city"  value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}  >
        <option value="">City</option>
          <option value="Lancaster">Lancaster</option>
          <option value="London">London</option>
        </select>
              
        <ul>
          { this.state.cines.map(cine => <li>* {cine.Name}</li>)}
        </ul>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Is it a typo? It should be `Select` in order to use the `react-select` component. In your code, you're using native html select.

Comment: yeah, thanks - looks like I was mixing old and new